# Как вызвать функцию в Python несколько раз?

Tags: python, функции

Суть в том,чтобы после завершения игры можно было выбрать один из вариантов (да/нет) и продолжить игру не останавливая программу. Третий день изучения Python,не могу додуматься.Чайник.Попробовал несколько вариантов:функция внутри функции,while.

`

```
import random
popitka=0
print('Как тебя зовут?')
name=input()
print('Приветствую,',name,'. Игра называется "Угадай число"')
print('Попробуй отгадать число от 1 до 20. У тебя 6 попыток. Удачи')
def play():
        number=random.randint(1,20)
        for popitka in range(1,7):
            guess=int(input())
            if guess<number:
                print('число слишком маленькое')
            if guess>number:
                print('число слишком большое')
            if guess==number:
                break
        if guess==number:
            popitka=str(popitka)
            print('Поздравляю,',name,'Ты отгадал число с',popitka,'попытки')
        if guess!=number:
            print('Увы,',name,'. Ты проиграл')
        return guess
play()
print('Хочешь попробовать еще раз?(да/нет)')
again=str(input())
if again=='да':
    play()
elif again=='нет':
    print('Спасибо за игру!')`
```

Данный вариант выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/обучение/guessGAME1.py", line 27, in <module>
    play()

  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/обучение/guessGAME1.py", line 10, in play
    guess=int(input())

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '
```

Comment: Ошибка возникает в функции `play`, то есть в самой реализации игры. Это произошло, потому что Вы ввели пробел, вместо числа (`int` не может преобразовать `' '` в число).

Comment: Касаемо вопроса, Вы должны обернуть последние 6 строк кода в цикл `while`, а в ветку `elif` (лучше в `else`) написать так же `break`, который прервёт цикл, чтобы завершить программу.

Answer (score 4):

```
print('Хочешь попробовать еще раз?(да/нет)')
again = input()
while again == 'да':
    play()

    print('Хочешь попробовать еще раз?(да/нет)')
    again = input()

print('Спасибо за игру!')
```

Хорошо бы реализовать это с помощью do...while, но такой конструкции нет в Python

Answer (score 3):

Альтерантивный вариант ответа pagislav:

```
while True:
    print('Хочешь попробовать еще раз?(да/нет)')
    again = input()

    if (again != 'да')
        break

    play()

print('Спасибо за игру!')
```

Answer (score 2):

или рекурсией

```
def play():
    print('play')
    return main()

def main(ex='да'):
    if (not ex) or (input(f'Хочешь попробовать еще раз? ({ex}/нет): ') == ex):
        return play()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(ex='')
```